# How to bind a dictionary to a gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, gridview, dictionary

Is it possible to automatically bind a Dictionary to a Gridview? The closest I've got is:

```
Dictionary<string, myObject> MyDictionary = new Dictionary<string, myObject>();
// Populate MyDictionary here.
Grid1.DataSource = MyDictionary.Values;
Grid1.DataBind();
```

This binds the properties in myObject to the gridview, but I'd like to get the key as well. If it's not possible, is there an alternative, e.g. use a repeater? Thanks.

Comment: Are you talking about DataGridView ( which I am not familiar with ) and not GridView as done for ListView? If so I guess my answer doesn't apply.

Comment: For the time being I've just put two asp.net gridviews side by side, one binded to MyDictionary.Keys and the other MyDictionary.Values.

Answer (score 3):

You need to bind the columns to "Key" and "Value", I believe.

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
var data = MyDictionary.Select(x => new List<object>{x.Key, x.Value});
```

This will give you an `IEnumerable<List<object>>`, where the `IEnumerable` represents the "rows" and within each row the `List<object>` represents the "columns."

This would be slightly different if `myObject` is a collection type. I can't be certain from your code, but it doesn't look like this is the case.

Comment: Would .GetEnumerator() do the same?

Comment: @Ing The enumeration would be objects of type `KeyValuePair<string, myObject>`.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately we're still on .NET 2.0 so I don't think that will work in my case. myObject isn't a collection type.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way is to convert into List>

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, object>> list = new List<KeyValuePair<string, object>>();
list.AddRange(dictionary);
Grid1.DataSource = list;
```

this also allows to do easy sorting:

```
list.Sort(delegate...);
```

then pass it as the DataSource.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea how well dictionary works as a itemsSource. I guess not at all unless Dictionary implements IEnumerable or ICollection.

You could however create your own object that holds a Key string property and your Object and have a collection of such items. However that will lack many things Dictionary has ( like unique Keys and such ).

Perhaps Dictionary has a ToList() method

Does it give you an error when putting the Dictionary as a source. If not perhaps you have to set the DisplayMemberPath on the columns as Value and Key.

Comment: As a matter of fact, dictionaries do implement `IEnumerable` and `ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>` and `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s4ys34ea.aspx

Comment: Then I can't see why it can't be used as a itemsSource for a ListView just like any other collection.

Answer (score 1):

Per the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource.aspx), the DataSource must be an object that implements one of the following interfaces:

- The IList interface, including one-dimensional arrays.
- The IListSource interface, such as the DataTable and DataSet classes.
- The IBindingList interface, such as the BindingList class.
- The IBindingListView interface, such as the BindingSource class.

Dictionary does not implement any of those interfaces.  The closest you can get would be to use `List<KeyValuePair<string, myObject>>`.

Comment: That's for the WinForms DataGridView control, not for the ASP.NET GridView control.