# Bind GridView from dictionary asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, dictionary, gridview

I manage to fill my gridview in a classic way with my dictionary, but what I would like to do is put the keys in column and the values in row instead of having the classic view with two columns key | Value.

So I tried adding the columns to the gridview but I got an error 'Could not find a field or property' employee_type 'in the selected data source.'

I think i've read all the similar subject but none of them explain my problem

Thank you for your help

my aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> dico = new Dictionary<string, string>();
 
            dico.Add("type_employe","salarié");
            dico.Add("Nom","Doe");
            dico.Add("Prenom","John");
            GridView1.DataSource = dico;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
```

my aspx

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="type_employe" HeaderText="Type employé" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Nom" HeaderText="Nom"  />      
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Prenom" HeaderText="Prenom"  />
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: There are some limitations to binding a dictionary, have you looked at this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4627143/how-to-bind-a-dictionary-to-a-gridview

Comment: The data field is `type_employe`, not `employee_type` as it appears on the error message.

Comment: @derloopkat sorry it's because the translation.

Comment: @Pete-S- Yes I already look it but i don't realy understand becaus when I set the iEnumerable on the datasource i've the same problem, instead the two columns key|Value i've capacity|count

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `AutoGenerateColumns` to false, and you can just use `Key` and `Value` of the dictionary in your `GridView`, like this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Key" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Value" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

If you need to customize the HeaderText, you can try using a custom object for your dictionary value, then you would be able to use the custom properties of that object in your `GridView` columns. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20747966/how-to-bind-dictionary-with-containing-list-to-grid-view) for an example.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I already try to set AutoGenerateColumns to false and i've the same error. I see the answer you give but I would like to know if it's possible to do what he does in the answer exemple but whithout creating a custom object. 
I would realy like to know why I've this error